# How to save HTML with indentation of attributes?

Tags: php, simplexml, domdocument

I have this result (with $dom->saveHTML()):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Complete!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foo" class="bar baz" data-foo="a" data-bar="b" data-baz="c"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I want save result with indentation of attributes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Complete!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foo"
                class="bar baz"
                data-foo="a"
                data-bar="b"
                data-baz="c"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How make it with native(?) php DOMDocument/DOMNode/DOMElement/somethingelse?

UPD: Yes! I really need that specific formatting for human readable.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Besides: why would you really _need_ that specific formatting?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, yes, really need. libxml2 (C language) have this feature (likely). But here need php implementation.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem for example (Ctrl+U): https://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/kiwi.svg

Comment: Change the formatting (ie write the entirey `<path>` tag on a single line, replacing all new lines with a single space in the `d` attribute: it doesn't matter one bit: the SVG still looks the same, and the markup is still equally valid. The only formatting related functions in libxml2 I've found sofar are [listed here](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlwriter.html#xmlTextWriterSetIndent) BTW, and a quick canter through the php source on github tells me they're not bound in such a way you can use them to format the output of a single tag

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, no, my question only for attributes, only for my example.

Comment: Well, to which my answer is: AFAIK libxml2 doesn't support formatting tags like that (well, not directly anyway), and I'm absolutely sure that PHP doesn't support it.

Answer (score -1):

Himself answered. Maybe this will be a good solution:

```
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
$html = html_entity_decode($html, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$html = explode("\n", $html);
foreach ($html as $num => $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^(\s*<[a-z]+\s+)([^>]+)(>)(.*)$/s', $line, $m)) {
        $offset = ceil(mb_strlen($m[1]) / 4);
        $attrs  = preg_split('/"\s+/', $m[2]);
        $attrs  = join("\"\n" . str_repeat('    ', $offset), $attrs);
        $html[$num] = $m[1] . $attrs . $m[3] . $m[4];
    }
}
$html = join("\n", $html);
```